# Binding button to subprogram with a key

Tags: python, tkinter

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.resizable('False', 'False')

#functions

def entered(): #Receives input by the user and deletes what it has written. 
   value = entry.get()
   entry.delete(0,'end')

def delete_insert(event):#Deletes what it's written by default in the entry widget.
   entry.delete(0, 'end')
   entry.config(fg = 'black')

def add_insert(event):
   entry.insert(0, 'Click Here')

frame = tk.Frame(win)
frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

button_entry = tk.Button(frame)
button_entry.pack(side = 'right')
button_entry.config(text = 'Buscar', command = entered)
button_entry.bind('Control-Enter', entered) #Keep this line in mind please.

entry = tk.Entry(frame)
entry.pack(side = 'right', padx = 5)
entry.insert(0,'Click Here') #Default text in entry widget.
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', delete_insert)
entry.bind('<FocusOut>', add_insert)

win.mainloop()
```

### Output:

[image: output]

### Question:

The line of code which binds `button_entry` with `entered()` subprogramn when pressing `Enter` doesn't seem work.

```
button_entry.bind('<Control-Enter>', entered)
```

Why not? When `entered()` subprogramn is run, it deletes the text inserted in `entry` widget

```
def entered(event):
    ....

    entry.delete(0, 'end')

....

entry.insert(0,'Click here')
```

Thus, my **goal** is, when the button `button_entry` is activated by `Enter` key, it runs subprogram `entered()`. Therefore, it deletes the text inserted in `entry` by the user.

[image: desired_output]

### What I've tried:

I add the parameter `event` to `entered()` as follows `entered(event)`. Like with the other functions so the binding would work. Unfortunately, when you click `button_entry` you get the following error:

```
TypeError: entered() missing 1 requiered positional argument: 'event'
```

Although, If you click `Enter`, the key on your keyboard, nothing happens, or atleast it seems like it because the subprogram I've bound to `button_entry` isn't executed

What I'm trying to accomplish is similar to what you do when you *google things*, you input what you want in the search engine and then click enter on your keyboard.

Comment: Is it the Enter key or Control and Enter you want to bind?

Comment: I want to bind `button_entry` to `entered()`.

Comment: Aren't you doing that when setting command equal to 'entered' when you create the button?

Comment: assign `event=None`.  Also, note that your button needs to have the focus to take key events. It would be better if you use `entry.bind('<Control-Return>', entered)`

Comment: @JacksonPro What does `event = None` do?

Comment: @JacksonPro The error isn't showing anymore when I click the button but nothing happens when I click enter yet. By the way, don't you mean `button_entry.bind(---)`?

Comment: @Nameless you are assigning a default value. event takes `None` if no argument is passed when calling the function. No, I mean `entry.bind('<Control-Return>', entered)` Your button has to have the focus to take Key events. When you type in the text box the focus would be in the entry widget hence `button_entry.bind()` is not likely to work.

Comment: @JacksonPro What I did now is: added `entry.bind('<Control-Return>', entered)` and deleted `button_entry.bind(----)`.

Comment: @JacksonPro The subprogram `def entered(event = None):` isn't executed when I click enter, so yes. What I want is to enter instead of clicking `button_entry` so It runs the subprogram.

Comment: Which key do you want to do the triggering.

Comment: use `entry.bind('<Return>', entered)`

Comment: @CoolCloud Enter key.

Comment: It is called 'Return'. Plus your button does not have focus, use `win.bind()` or `entry.bind()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Doesn't work.

Comment: @Jacksonpro Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes, your binding key is wrong and your function call also seems wrong. Plus you are binding to the button, then it requires the button to have focus, only then `bind` will work. So your code would be:

```
def entered(event=None): 
   value = entry.get()
   entry.delete(0,'end')

entry.bind('<Return>',lambda event: entered()) # Bind the enter key to the entry
# OR win.bind(same thing above)
```

`event` is set to `None` so that when the button tries to call this function and no args are passed, it wont throw an error at you.

Comment: I tried it. `Button_entry` isn't do its job. The code isn't executed when I click `Return`. Just to clarify, instead of clicking the button, I want to click `Return` and yield the same result as If I've clicked it.

Comment: @Nameless By 'Return', you mean enter key right?

Comment: Yes, not the space  bar, not anything, just the key with the *curved arrow* on it, `Return`.

Comment: This code works for me, make sure you are using the same code. Ill add the entire code. Keep in mind, you will have to have focus on the entry widget for this to work or use `win.bind()`.

Comment: I have a doubt. Why `entry('<Return>', entered)` and not `entry('<Control-Return>', entered)` (this doesn't work).

Comment: @Nameless You are binding to different keys, first is just enter key. Second is Ctrl + Enter key.